# Is it content multiplication?

Tags: seo

I have 2 url width the totally same content because I'd like if a subpage could reach in easily (short name) and valuable urls too:

***domain.com/name_of_company***

***domain.com/name_of_company/address_of_company***

And I have a third url:
***domain.com/name_of_company/products_of_company***
This page would be the same as ***domain.com/name_of_company*** but with more content at the top of the page.

What you think if it's good way or I should forget 'cause I'll be punished by google?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the behaviour of a search engine service / asking for SEO advice. (It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].)

Comment: This question is off-topic and would belong on [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have identical pages, but then you should add a [canonical link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) to the pages, which tells which URL you consider to be the original. That way search engines can immediately see that the pages were intended to be identical.

This will not only avoid being punished for duplicate content, it will also allow for the search engines to count incoming links to both URLs as links to the original page.

For the third page, you could consider if you need to repeat all the content from the other page. Having some content repeated from page to page is common (e.g. page footer), but too much repeated content is not valuable. Even if you are not directly punished for the repetition, there is a risk that some of the repeated content is simply ignored.